# sed - add tags around repeating strings

Tags: sed

I want to add html tags around my markup language block tags

Content of file

```
=====
a
=====
========
B
========
=====
c=
=====
========
D=
========
```

Desired output:

```
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
a
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
B
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
c=
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
D=
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
```

What I already tried:

```
sed 's/^\(===\+\)/<pattern-start>\1/' file
sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/\(<pattern-start>===\+.*<pattern-start>===\+\)/<block-start>\1<block-end>/g' file
```

block tags won't hit all desired occurrences (only first and last)

```
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
a
<pattern-start>=====
<pattern-start>========
B
<pattern-start>========
<pattern-start>=====
c=
<pattern-start>=====
<pattern-start>========
D=
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
```

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/\(===\+[^=]*\)\(===\+\)/<block-start><pattern-start>\1<pattern-start>\2<block-end>/g' file
```

all tags get messed up when I use = in the block

```
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
a
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
B
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
=====
c=
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
D=
<block-start><pattern-start>=====<pattern-start>===<block-end>
```

Comment: `':a;N;$!ba;` - well, you have to remember "state" - that you are inside a block or not. So reading it all to memory, it's not going to go well, and because regexes are greedy, you will match everything (like in your first example - `block-end` is on the end, because regex is greedy). But still you could use backreference most probably with proper matching of beginning and end and newlines. Shouldn't the second `<pattern-start>` be `<pattern-end>`??

Comment: `===\+[^=]*` is stranve - it matches `===` followed by everything __but not__ `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^=/{:a;N;/^((=+)\n.*\n)\2$/!ba;s//<block-start><pattern-start>\1<pattern-start>\2<block-end>/}' -E file
```

If the line begins with a `=`, append the next line until the first line matches the last. Then format the pattern space as required.

Or if you prefer:

```
a="<block-start>"; b="<pattern-start>"; c="<block-end>"
sed '/^=/{:a;N;/^((=+)\n.*\n)\2$/!ba;s//'$a$b'\1'$b'\2'$c'/}' -E file
```

Comment: thanks, is there also a way how to get rid of === in process?
that would be my other use case

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy with `awk`, in case you are ok with `awk` please try following then(written and tested with shown samples).

```
awk -v start="<block-start><pattern-start>" -v start_line="<pattern-start>" -v end_line="<block-end>" '
/^=/ && found==""{
  print start $0
  next
}
!/^=/{
  found=1
  print
  next
}
/^=/ && found{
  print start_line $0 end_line
  found=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed for above.

```
awk -v start="<block-start><pattern-start>" -v start_line="<pattern-start>" -v end_line="<block-end>" '  ##Starting awk and mentioning variables here.
/^=/ && found==""{                 ##Checking condition if a line starts from = AND checking found is NULL then do following.
  print start $0                   ##Printing variable start and current line here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!/^=/{                             ##Checking condition if a line is NOT starting with = then do following.
  found=1                          ##Setting found value to 1 here.
  print                            ##Printing current line here.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^=/ && found{                     ##Checking condition if line starts with = and found is SET then do following.
  print start_line $0 end_line     ##Printing variable start_line current line and end_line here.
  found=""                         ##Nullify found variable here.
}
'  Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is completely inappropriate for this job. Even if you could figure out the magical incantation to do this with one sed version it'd be an illegible stream of single-character runes, almost certainly non-portable and not extensible if/when your requirements evolve.

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/^=+$/ {
    $0=( (++c) % 2 ? "<block-start><pattern-start>" $0 : "<pattern-start>" $0 "<block-end>" )
} 1' file
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
a
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
B
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
c=
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
D=
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
```

and so would this if you prefer to separate the definition of the formats from the use of the formats:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    fmt[0] = "<block-start><pattern-start>%s"
    fmt[1] = "<pattern-start>%s<block-end>"
}
/^=+$/ { $0 = sprintf(fmt[(c++) % 2],$0) }
1' file
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
a
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
B
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>=====
c=
<pattern-start>=====<block-end>
<block-start><pattern-start>========
D=
<pattern-start>========<block-end>
```

Comment: all your points are valid and your awk is clearly more readable then sed, but I need/want to do in place replacements and gawk isn't available everywhere by default

Comment: Only GNU sed and BSD sed support "inplace" editing and anywhere either of them is available, GNU awk is also available. Also, "inplace" editing with these and perl, ruby, etc. creates a temp file behind the scenes so you never actually need to do "inplace" editing, you can always trivially do `cmd 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` - the ability to do "inplace" editing is just not something to choose any specific tool based on, it's syntactic sugar at best.

Answer (score 0):

My `sed` solution!:

```
sed '
    /^===/{
        h
        s/^/<block-start><pattern-start>/
        : repeat; {
            n
            G
            /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!{
                s/\n.*//
                b repeat
            }
            s//<pattern-start>\1<block-end>/
        }
    }
'
```

1. If the line starts with `===` then hold the line and add the `<block-start><pattern-start>` thingy.
2. Then read next line. Add the holded part to current line to see if the same count of `=====` was found in the readed line.
3. If not remove the grabbed line and repeat.
4. If it was, add the `<pattern-start>====<block-end>` part.

Comment: thanks, it works but I'll choose shorter version provided by potong as solution